# MixedRealityToolkit spectator cannot use the “copy＆customize” fuction

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

when I hit the “copy＆customize” button, it cannot create a duplicate file, this error also happens when I try to use the “clone” button. my unity version is 2020.3.29f1, and my MRTK version is 2.7.0. I will really appreciate it if somebody could help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project and importing MRTK again? Are there any error messages when you click the Clone button? Any screenshots will be helpful. Also, you can try dragging the Profile from Packages under Assets and then clone it.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I have imported MRTK a few times, and also created a new project, but it still didn't work. the problem is when I click the clone button nothing came out, only an empty file "CustomProfiles" is created under the "MixedRealityToolkit.Generated" folder, but this file contains nothing, and such a problem also happens in the higher version like Unity 2021.3.9f1.

Comment: I did a test on Unity2021.3.9f1 and couldn't reproduce your issue. Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to troubleshoot? And have you tried upgrading MRTK to the latest version?
Also, the method used for cloning is **CloneProfile()** in **Packages->Mixed Reality Toolkit Foundation->Core->Inspectors->Profiles->MixedRealityProfileCloneWindow**, you can do some tests on it.